# jQueryUI stencils for Evolus Pencil Project

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, mockups, mockup-tool

Does anyone know where I can download some jQueryUI and/or jQuery Mobile stencils for [Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Home.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to create your own but maybe:

- http://graffletopia.com/stencils/792
- http://forum.jquery.com/topic/psd-for-the-jquery-mobile-template